# Exercise about diffeomorphism induced on a subset of $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

I have to determine if the following maps $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ induce a diffeomorphism $Z \to Z$:

- $f:X \mapsto AX, \ A\in O(d)$ and $Z=S^{d-1}$;
- $f:X \mapsto AX, \ A\in O(d)$ and $Z=\partial(\mathbb R^d \setminus D_{d}(0,1) )$;
- with $d=2$, $f(X)=ABCX$. Here $B\in O(3)$, and $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a &0&0\\ 0&-b&0\\ 0&0&-c \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ \ C=\begin{pmatrix} \frac 1 a &0&0\\ 0&-\frac 1 b&0\\ 0&0&\frac 1 c \end{pmatrix}.$$
  $Z=\partial \{(x\ y\ z)^t:(\frac x a)^2+(\frac y b)^2+(\frac z c)^2 < 1 \}$, and $a,b,c\gt 0$.

I really don't know what to do in this exercise: the only thing I thought, for the first two points, is that every matrix in $O(d)$ has $d$ eigenvectors that are the fixed point of the map $f$; and the only diffeomorphism with a fixed point is the identity. However this reasoning is not consistent, because the eigenvectors of $A$ could be complex, and we are only considering real spaces. For example, a rotation in three dimension has only a real eigenvector, while two dimensional rotations clearly don't fix any points other than $0$. So with these reasoning the only thing that I concluded about the first two points is that, when $d=3$, $f$ isn't a diffeomorphism for every $A$. For what regards the third point, I think I should prove that if $X\in Z$ then $ABCX\in Z$, and that $f $ has not fixed points, but I have no clue on how to do it. Can you help me with this type of exercises? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hint(s): $O(d)$ preserves norm, are bijection, have inverses and are smooth. For the second one, do you mean $D_d$? I don’t see how $D_{d+1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Also what is $C$?

Comment: I’m gonna assume it’s $C = \text{diag}(1/a, -1/b, 1,c)$. In which case, have you thought about how $C$ affects $Z$?

Comment: @OsamaGhani thanks for your help; I corrected what didn't make sense in my answer. Then, for the first two points you're right: I was thinking that the differential in a fixed point is necessarily zero, but this isn't true. For the third point we have that $Cz\in S^{2}$, with $z\in Z$, so applying $B$ we obtain again a point in $S^{2}$. Finally, $A$ sends it to a point in $Z$ (we just need to do the substitutions). For the same reasons of the previous points, $f$ is bijective, smooth and with smooth inverse, so it is a diffeomorphism $Z\to Z$.

Comment: That's exactly right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s work out the first one, and hopefully this should clue you in on the other two. First note that $f(x) = Ax$ where $A \in O(n)$ preserves length of vectors. In particular, since $S^{n-1}$ is the set of all vectors with length $1$, this descends to a map $f’:S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$. $f’$ is bijective since $f$ is bijective since $A$ is invertible. Moreover $f’$ is smooth since it’s the composition of the inclusion $S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$. Moreover it has a smooth inverse given by $f(x) = A^{-1}x$, so this is a diffeomorphism.

As a hint for the third case, think about what $A$ and $C$ really do here. $A$ and $C$ are *almost* inverses (I’m not sure if there was a typo or not) so this is *almost* like a change of basis (up to signs).